# Comparing QWidgets

Tags: c++, qt

How can I compare QWidgets?
Lets say I have a list and would like to change the sizes of Widgets which are only `QPushButton`:

For example, is there any function or method to do this?

```
QList<QLayoutItem *> itemList;

if(itemList->Items->type() == QPushButton)
{
  item.setGeometry(newRect);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, actually. [QObject::inherits()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#inherits) is one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); ++i) {
    if (itemList[i]->inherits("QPushButton")) {
        itemList[i]->setGeometry(newRect);
    }
}
```

Another way is using [qobject_cast](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#qobject_cast), which is what I recommend. It returns a null pointer if the object does not inherit (directly or not) from the class you cast to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); ++i) {
    if (qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(itemList[i])) {
        itemList[i]->setGeometry(newRect);
    }
}
```

Note that qobject_cast does *not* need RTTI support to be enabled in the compiler.

And there's of course the standard C++ dynamic_cast which does need RTTI support enabled:

```
for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); ++i) {
    if (dynamic_cast<QPushButton*>(itemList[i])) {
        itemList[i]->setGeometry(newRect);
    }
}
```

Another method that would appear OK at first glance, but ultimately should not be used in this case, is QMetaObject::className(). Do not use this, because you'll get false negatives with QPushButton subclasses.

The reason I recommend qobject_cast is because it allows the compiler to check the typename. This is important when changing the name of a class. The compiler isn't able to check that when using the string-based QObject::inherits() function, so the code will continue to compile without problems but it won't work at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `QMetaObject::className` to get the class type if it's got the `QObject` meta type information, which `QPushButton` should. More information on the docs [here: QMetaObject className](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetaobject.html#className).

Comment: Yeah, but `inherits` handles subclasses as well.

Comment: As far as I'm aware `className` will actually look up ancestors to find a match. So `MyPushButton` inherits `QPushButton` but does not specify meta information, so `className` returns on `QPushButton`. At least that's what the documentation specifies: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/metaobjects.html

Answer (score 0):

The standard C++ way is to use `dynamic_cast<QPushButton*>(widget)`.

Qt provides alternatives through it's meta-object system.  One is `qobject_cast`, which works similarly to `dynamic_cast` but might be preferable.

Alternatively you can get the class name of any QObject through its meta-object.  For example:

```
if( strcmp(widget->metaObject()->className(), "QPushButton") == 0 )
```

See [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/metaobjects.html) for more information on Qt meta-objects.

Comment: I was going to check this as an answer, but the answer above explained not using `className`. This was working as well...